Error measuring the voltage with a multimeter?
When testing my batteries, I wanted to test the battery on my multimeter without taking it out because I wouldn't have other new 9v batteries if I did. But, it just displayed a 1 (which means an error). I knew it would happen, but why did it happen? The answer must be something stupid… Since the multimeter needs power, it is connected to a 9v battery. I tried to test the battery connected to the same multimeter using that multimeter.

Missing a lot of information. What kind of meter, how did you connect it, what configuration was your meter it?

what do you mean by what kind of meter? It says multimeter.

Check that the range setting is able to measure greater than 9V

It's set at 20v.

Could be weak battery in your multimeter. Too low battery voltage = high readings.

I measured the same battery outside of the multimeter.

There are many different meters all with different quirks and characteristics. What is the brand and model number of the meter you are using.

If I understand you correctly, you attempted to measure the voltage of the 9 V battery in your multimeter while it was powering your multimeter, and it gave an error reading.
Since you didn't give the model of the multimeter, or its schematic, we don't know its internals. However, multimeters tend to follow a similar pattern in their design. Many of the "cheap" multimeters are based upon the Renesas ICL7106 or ICL7107 3 1/2 digit A/D converter for LED/LCD displays.
Here is the datasheet's "typical application" for the ICL7106. It is missing all the bells and whistles that are found in even a cheap multi-meter, but it will greatly assist in our understanding.

Note that there is one pair of pins that are connected to the 9V battery for power. These are pins 1 and 26 or V+ and V-. There is another pair of pins that are used for analog input. These are pins 31 and 30 or IN HI and IN LO. Especially important is that in this circuit IN LO is connected directly to pin 32 or COM.
Now let's look at some electrical specifications from the datasheet.

When you probe the negative terminal of your battery, you are connecting IN LO (hence COM) to V-. Per the electrical specification, this should "turn off the COM circuit". I assume this is what is giving you the error output.
In short, most multimeters are design to have a floating power supply, i.e. a battery, and at least some do not tolerate having their "COM" input pin pulled down to the negative voltage of their battery.

+1 for the correct answer. OC for the ICL7106 was Intersil in the seventies. They were bought by Harris in the 1980s, and then by the Japanese company Renesas in 2017.  They were copied by Maxim and others. Similar front end circuitry is available today in updated Chinese-designed chips.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Battery voltage measurement technique.
@MathKeepsMeBusy's answer is correct. The COM terminal is at an offset voltage from one of the battery terminals. To measure the battery voltage:

Take measurement Figure 1a. (Let's say it's 2.8 V.)
Take measurement Figure 1b. (Let's say it's -5.7 V.)
The battery voltage is the difference between the two. 2.8 - (-5.7) = 8.5 V.

I learned this in the late 1970s! It's funny how some things haven't changed much.

Nice technique!

A multimeter measures the potential difference between two points in a circuit, but it requires that those two points to be electrically isolated from the meter's own internal circuitry. In other words, both of the measured potentials must be entirely independent of the multimeter's own power supply and circuitry.
Since the battery powering the multimeter does not have this independence, or isolation, connecting either of the meter's own battery terminals to either probe will upset the biasing of amplifiers inside the meter, and cause an incorrect reading.
You're probably OK, but I wouldn't be surprised if that also caused damage to the meter.

You might be interested in my answer.
